# How to merge and close a PyPDF without previous inputs being attached

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, pypdf

Im having an issue when merging multiple pdf's because i do have to loop between folders and merge the two files that match.
this was easily done but when i:

```
input1.append(file1)
input2.append(file2)
PDFFileMerger.write(output)
```

the merging occurs, but the next iteration includes the previous inputs and so on, making the last one a huge pdf file que the occurrences repeating on each other

```
for i in range(nPdfs):
    abr = onlypdf[i]
    abr = abr.replace('.pdf', '')
    for j in range(nXl):
        pdf_file = open('SEPTIEMBRE DE 2020/' + onlyfiles[j], 'rb')
        read_pdf = pdf.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
        number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
        page = read_pdf.getPage(0)
        page_content = page.extractText()
        if abr in page_content:
            file1 = onlypdf[i]
            file2 = onlyfiles[j]
    print(file1)
    print(file2)
    print(file1+' esta en '+file2)
    input1 = open('Combinadora/documentos/'+file1, 'rb')
    input2 = open('SEPTIEMBRE DE 2020/'+file2, 'rb')
    merger.append(input1)
    merger.append(input2)
    input1.close()
    input2.close()
    print('archivo creado')
    output = open(abr+'-'+file2, 'wb')
    merger.write(output)
    output.close()
```

This is my code, am i screwing it in the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyPDF is a great library but I had some problems too with memory. So generally I used separate processes creating the merger (killed after job) or you can delete (del) the actual object. Keep in mind that even if you find a tricky way to surpass this problem, memory leaks can happen so I strongly suggest creation and killing of processes.